# Using boolean values instead of BOOL values with MAKEWORD / MAKEWPARAM

Tags: c++, winapi

```
// Rebuild the "Assign Flags"
m_dwStudentAssignFlags = MAKEWPARAM(
    MAKEWORD(bIncluded[INDEX(StudentAssign::kItem1)] ? TRUE : FALSE, bIncluded[INDEX(StudentAssign::kItem2)] ? TRUE : FALSE),
    MAKEWORD(bIncluded[INDEX(StudentAssign::kItem3)] ? TRUE : FALSE, bIncluded[INDEX(StudentAssign::kItem4)] ? TRUE : FALSE));
```

`bIncluded` is a fixed array of 4 elements of type `boolean`.

The above code works but I wanted to know if there is any specific reason why I can't simplify the code down to:

```
// Rebuild the "Assign Flags"
m_dwStudentAssignFlags = MAKEWPARAM(
    MAKEWORD(bIncluded[INDEX(StudentAssign::kItem1)], bIncluded[INDEX(StudentAssign::kItem2)]),
    MAKEWORD(bIncluded[INDEX(StudentAssign::kItem3)], bIncluded[INDEX(StudentAssign::kItem4)]));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MAKEWPARAM(a, b)` uses C-casts under the hood, something like

```
(unsigned long)(a)
```

or

```
(unsigned __int64)(a)
```

Casting `bool` to `unsigned long` or `unsigned __int64` is perfectly valid, and the C++ Standard (4.7/4, [conv.integral]) guarantees that casting `false` and `true` will produce `0` and `1`:

> If the source type is `bool`, the value `false` is converted to zero and
>   the value `true` is converted to one.

`FALSE` and `TRUE` are `#define`s for `0` and `1`. So, your simplification is valid and is equivalent to the original code.

Comment: The exact definition of `MAKEWPARAM()` is `#define MAKEWPARAM(l, h)      ((WPARAM)(DWORD)MAKELONG(l, h))` where `MAKELONG()` is defined as `#define MAKELONG(a, b)      ((LONG)(((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(a)) & 0xffff)) | ((DWORD)((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(b))`.  See the definitions in `winuser.h` and `windef.h`, respectively.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, and `DWORD_PTR` is a `typedef` for `ULONG_PTR`, which is in turn a `typedef` for `unsigned long` or `unsigned __int64` for Win32/64.